# Unable to mock a method - Mockito - Kotlin

Tags: unit-testing, kotlin, mocking, mockito

I am trying to mock a method (getQualityControlCheckDataForUplift(ArgumentMatchers.any(), ArgumentMatchers.anyFloat())) to return qcchecks which I have defined in my test case but I get an error.

Any suggestions on where I am doing it wrong please

`org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException: Unable to create mock instance of type 'QualityControlChecksDataProvider'`

QualityControlChecksDataProvider

```
class QualityControlChecksDataProvider @Inject constructor(
    private val offlineDataStorage: OfflineDataStorage,
    private val app: App
) {
    private val mapOfQCChecksForMilestone = LinkedHashMap<String, ArrayList<QualityControlCheck>?>()

 fun getQualityControlCheckDataForUplift(qualityControlMilestone: QualityControlMilestone, uplift: Float):
        ArrayList<QualityControlCheck>? {
        val qcChecksForUplift: ArrayList<QualityControlCheck>? = ArrayList()
        val qcChecksForMilestone = mapOfQCChecksForMilestone[qualityControlMilestone.milestoneText]
        qcChecksForMilestone?.forEach {
            if (it.uplift == uplift) qcChecksForUplift?.add(it)
        }
        return qcChecksForUplift
    }

}
```

In my unit test this is how I am trying to mock

```
@Test
    fun `upliftedVolumeUpdated abcd` () {

  val qualityControlCheckDataProvider = spy(QualityControlChecksDataProvider::class.java)
        every(qualityControlCheckDataProvider.getQualityControlCheckDataForUplift(ArgumentMatchers.any(), ArgumentMatchers.anyFloat())).thenReturn(qualityControlChecks)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think a spy is what you want here I think you want a mock. Give this a try

```
@Test
fun `upliftedVolumeUpdated abcd` () {
    val qualityControlDataProviderMock = mock<QualityControlChecksDataProvider> {
        on { getQualityControlCheckDataForUplift(any(), any()) } doReturn qualityControlChecks
    }
}
```